# Subclassing Fabric JS Type in Typescript Causes error when deserialize

Tags: javascript, typescript, fabricjs

I extend Fabric Js Default type:

```
export class Button extends fabric.Rect {


  public text: string;
  public textColor: string;
  public font = '30px Arial';
  public action: ActionEnum;
  public type = 'button';


  constructor(options: IButttonOptions) {
    super(options);
    if (options.font) {
      this.font = options.font;
    }
    this.text = options.text;
    this.textColor = options.textColor;
    this.action = options.action;
  }


  toDatalessObject(propertiesToInclude?: string[]): any {
    propertiesToInclude = (propertiesToInclude || []).concat(
      ['text', 'textColor', 'font', 'action']
    );

    return super.toDatalessObject(propertiesToInclude);
  }


  _render(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    super._render(ctx);
    console.log('test');
    ctx.font = this.font;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.textColor;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(this.text, 0, 10);
  }
```

And i want serialize/desearialize canvas like this:

```
var json = canvas.toDatalessJSON();
canvas.clear();
canvas.loadFromJSON(json); // cause error
```

But when i want load canvas with object defined above, i have exception "klass is undefined"

I Dont know how resolve this issue.Somebody can help?